# This is a proof involving limit points.

Tags: proof-theory

If p is a limit point of M prove that p must be a limit point from the left of M or from the right of M

So I know i need to use the definition of a limit point from the left which would be p is a limit point of (p-1,p) ∩ M and also the definition of a limit point from the right which would be p is a limit point of (p,p+1) ∩ M.

I have gathered information but I need to prove this formally.

Comment: What would happen if $p$ was neither a limit point from the left nor from the right?

Comment: You should say that M is in R.  Otherwise "from the right" and "from the left" make no sense.